# How to direct to file folder and execute specific file using batch command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im trying to make a batch file that directs to a specific tile folder and executes a file in that folder

ie:
`start cmd.exe "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\<folder>" & "runas /user:<user> "file.exe"`

but it's only directing to the folder not executing the file in that folder, why?

Comment: My first instinct would be to try: `runas /user@domain.ext "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\folder\file.exe"`

Comment: Similarly `runas /user:<localmachinename>\<username> "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\folder\file.exe"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create file with *.cmd extension (long time ago it may be *.bat ;-)), paste eg.

```
start cmd.exe 
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\
dir
pause
```

For me that worked.

Comment: In terms of the question asked, this is absolute rubbish. The first line opens an empty Command Prompt window, and the rest of the commands run in the original. The second changes directory, only if the current drive was already `C:`, the third line performs a directory listing of the current directory and the last line pauses execution. That means there is an empty cmd.exe window still open, no `runas` command has been invoked, and no `file.exe` has been, either. There is nothing in this answer which meets any of the criteria of the question. I have downvoted it for the reasons given above.

Comment: I have prepared such commands to show - only - how it works. 'pause' were needed to show the results, that this works. Once again - this is only example.